# template function taking array argument vs overload function taking pointer argument

Tags: c++

Consider the following code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

template <int size>
void func(const char (&arr)[size])
{
    //Prefer this function for const string literals.
    std::cout << "Array of " << size - 1 << " bytes" << std::endl;
}

void func(const char *arr)
{
    //Use this for all other strings that are not literals
    std::cout << "String of " << strlen(arr) << " bytes" <<std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    func("Hello!");
    return 0;
}
```

How do I ensure that the template function is called in the example instead of the overload?

What I would like it that the templated function is called on string literals while the other is available for all other cases. With the templated function, i can avoid calling the strlen(). In my application both functions finally create a string_view object.

I would like to know how an overload is preferred.

Comment: Can you make your function argument to be of type `std::string_view`?

Comment: See also [CWG issue 1789](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#1789). I would not expect it to be resolved in such a way that it will change previously unambiguous overload resolution, though. (Although the proposed resolution in the issue description would have that effect here.)

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that array-to-pointer conversions count as exact match rank when ranking standard conversion sequences during overload resolution. Since the array overload is a template the pointer overload thus becomes a better match.

You could add a proxy object for the pointer overload, to force it into a worse conversion sequence than that of the array overload for when the argument is of type `const char (&)[N]`:

```
namespace detail {
struct Proxy {
  Proxy(const char *ptr) : ptr_{ptr} {};
  operator const char *() const { return ptr_; }

private:
  const char *ptr_;
};
} // namespace detail

template <int size> void func(const char (&arr)[size]) {
  // Prefer this function for const string literals.
  std::cout << "Array of " << size - 1 << " bytes" << std::endl;
}

void func(detail::Proxy const &proxy) {
  // Use this for all other strings that are not literals
  std::cout << "String of " << strlen(proxy) << " bytes" << std::endl;
}

int main() {
  func("Hello!"); // Array of 6 bytes
  const char *str = "Hello!";
  func(str); // String of 6 bytes
}
```

Comment: This works as expected but the solution presented by 273k seems simpler and more elegant. Is there a preference between the two? Are there any gotcha's?

Comment: @KishoreJonnalagadda This solution will (in contrast to the one in your question) not work if called with an argument that must first be converted to `const char*` via user-defined conversion (because the user-defined conversion slot in the conversion sequence is already taken up by the proxy construction). Otherwise I don't see any problematic case on a quick look.

Comment: @KishoreJonnalagadda No real gotchas: what appears as a simpler solution, however, has. It allows neither to pass a prvalue pointer (can't bind to non-const lvalue reference) nor to pass an argument of type `const char * const` ([DEMO](https://wandbox.org/permlink/sdD2yQGa0Ru7zkUu)), and it moreover opens up a non-const contract which gives no promise to clients that the `func` call will not mutate the _pointer_ that was passed to it. Under the non-const contract of this approach, you could freely change what an argument _points to_ ([DEMO](https://wandbox.org/permlink/S0w6LsP7K1YmqyPA)).

Comment: There appears to be a problem with this when using a locally declared array but not a string literal.
```
int main()
{
    func("Hello!");
    char a[10];
    strcpy(a, "Hello!");
    func(a); //<-- should call string function, but uses the array function.
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The trick with a reference makes inexact match to `const char*` for a regular function.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

template <size_t size>
void func(const char (&arr)[size])
{
    //Prefer this function for const string literals.
    std::cout << "Array of " << size - 1 << " bytes" << std::endl;
}

void func(const char *&arr)
{
    //Use this for all other strings that are not literals
    std::cout << "String of " << strlen(arr) << " bytes" <<std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    func("Hello!");
    const char *s = "s";
    func(s);
    return 0;
}
```

Output

```
Array of 6 bytes
String of 1 bytes
```

Comment: Both answers work but i like this more for it's simplicity. Is there any red flag here?

Comment: @KishoreJonnalagadda It will not work with a prvalue pointer as argument, e.g. if `g` is a function returning `const char*`, then `func(g())` will fail. Similarly, it won't work for a non-`const`-qualified pointer.

Comment: @user17732522 The question does not ask about non-const chars.

Comment: @273K I didn't intend to claim that it does. I just listed some differences to the behavior of the functions in the question. Your edit won't work as expected however. It worked correctly only because `const char * &` wasn't able to bind a temporary from the array-to-pointer conversion, but `const char *const &` can. https://godbolt.org/z/51jb373v4

Comment: @user17732522 I don't get your comment about my edit and showing it working in the compiler explorer.

Comment: @273K With your edit the first output line will be `String of 6 bytes`, not `Array of 6 bytes` as it should.

Comment: @user17732522 Ok

Comment: @KishoreJonnalagadda In addition to this approach not allowing neither to pass a prvalue pointer (can't bind to non-const lvalue reference) nor to pass an argument of type `const char * const` ([DEMO](https://wandbox.org/permlink/sdD2yQGa0Ru7zkUu)), it moreover opens up a non-const contract which gives no promise to clients that the `func` call will not mutate the _pointer_ that was passed to it. Under the non-const contract of this approach, you could freely change what an argument _points to_ ([DEMO](https://wandbox.org/permlink/S0w6LsP7K1YmqyPA)).